# In the third Beis Hamikdash, will the outer gates have tall walls also on the outside?

Tags: commentaries, beis-hamikdash, ezekiel--the-book, third-temple

BH

In [Yechezkayl 40:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.40.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and some other pesukim it talks about the gates for the outer walls of {the Ezras  Nashim of} the third Beis Hamikdash:

> Then he came to the gate which looks toward the east, and went up by its stairs, and measured the threshold of the gate, which was one reed broad; and the other threshold of the gate, which was one reed broad.

It's hard to tell from [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.40.6?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) and the commentaries, but did the outer gates, on the outside, facing towards the temple mount, have long walls (60 amah) just like the ulam on the inside of the gates, or are the "sides" of the gate only within the cavity between the two sides of the wall itself but not extruding outwards?

Many 3d models and images online show an extrusion outside, as well as the Ulam on the inside, but some books show the outer gate as only from within the thickness of the wall and inwards, but not extruding out

I've tried to look through all of the commentaries I can find but I'm not sure where to look or who talks about it?

**Gates extruding out:**

[image]

[image]

Gates inside wall:

[image]

Comment: Did you see the work "The Third Beit HaMikdash" by the Tosafos Yom Tov? It's available online on Sefaria. It might be discussed over there?

Comment: @shmuel thanks I'll try to find it, I saw an English picture book by the same name that says it's based off tosafos yom tov, but their picture shows kind of a hybrid between the two and they don't cite exactly what he says about it

Comment: Here you go: https://www.sefaria.org/The_Third_Beit_HaMikdash?tab=contents

Comment: @shmuel thanks. I found the link earlier but it would help if someone can direct me to which section mentions it explicitly, if it does so, because other books I've seen quoted in his name talk about many other details of the gate except for that one, and then the verse in the question that not be the primary verse

Comment: Sorta related question- will the Kotel be a part of the third Beit Mikdash?

Comment: @CuriousYid kind of related, but that's dealing with the wall of the har habais, and on the western side, while this is asking about the wall of the ezras nashim, and on the eastern, northern and southern sides